# Two-stage Jenkins pipeline script doesn't lock onto needed nodes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline script where I want to kick off parallel builds on two different build machines, and once it's all done, perform some post-run activity like unstashing and publishing test results, creating an archive from all of the binaries and libraries generated, etc.

It basically looks like this, where 'master' is a MacOS machine and we've got a separate machine for Windows builds:

```
// main run stuff
parallel (
    "mac" : {
        node ('master') {                
            for (job in macJobs) {
                job.do()
            }
        }
    },
    "windows" : {
        node ('windowsMachine') {                
            for (job in windowsJobs) {
                job.do()
            }
        }
    }
}

node('master') {
    // post-run stuff        
}
```

If I kick off a single build with this script then it completes no problem.

But, if a second build kicks off while the first is still working through the `parallel` block (i.e. its polling SCM and someone did a push while the first build is still going), then the post-run block doesn't get executed until the second job's `parallel` block completes.

There's obviously a priority queue based on who gets to request the node first, but I'd like for one complete script run to finish before Jenkins moves on to the next, so we don't end up with jobs piling up on the post-run block which normally only takes a couple of seconds to complete...

How do I modify the script to do this? I've tried wrapping it all in a single `stage` block, but no luck there.

Answer (score 0):

I might guess that part of the problem lies around your post-run stuff sharing your master node with one of your parallel tasks.  Especially if your master node only has a one or two executors, which would definitely put it at 100% load with more than one concurrent build.

If this sounds like it might be part of your problem, you can try giving your post-run stuff a dedicated node to guarantee availability independent of triggered builds.  Or increase the executors available on your master node to guarantee that even if there are a couple concurrent builds, there are still executors available for those post-runs.

Jenkins doesn't really care about the origin of a block to execute.  So if you have two jobs running at the same time, and each uses the master node in two separate blocks.  There is a real chance the first block of each job will execute together before either of their second block is reached.  If your executor only has two executors available, then you may even end up with a starved queue for that node, but at the very least, an executor must become available before either of those second blocks can begin.

Comment: Ah yes, that's another thing I tried. Unfortunately, that just means the second job starts running the 'master' parallel block at the same time. Many of the jobs running in the parallel blocks are test jobs, which test real-time functionality and hence need to have the node all to themselves. Essentially the post-run stuff doesn't get pushed into the queue until a given jobs parallel block has completely finished. I either need a way to get it pushed to the queue sooner (tho it can't start until all of the other jobs finish), or just prevent other jobs stealing the node until this one is done.

Comment: I may not fully understand, it sounds like what you want to do is give the post-run it's own dedicated node.  You probably don't want to start trying to defer and reserve slots in your executor queue because that will potentially slow down everything as available executors may not be utilized as fast as they should be, or at all.  And as far as I know, you can't just inject something into the queue (nor should you I imagine).

Comment: If a node is to specifically have one executor, then giving that node a singular purpose will ensure that it keeps itself moving swimmingly as jobs have a need for it.  To have the node do business work and post-business work will create that bottleneck if two builds run in parallel and each need that node to satisfy multiple purposes.

Comment: Yeah, the nodes have 1 executor each and that's intentional. A separate node would be nice, but that's not an option (budget). I don't actually mind if I'm not building things as fast as possible, I just want the current build to completely finish before the next one starts. At the moment, any number of builds can get started during the first build's parallel block, and get pushed to the front of the queue before the first job's post-run gets a chance to. At which point the first build sits there spinning on its post-run block, while it waits for every other job's parallel block to end.

Comment: I should also note the parallel block can take ~15m to complete, while the post run block is mere seconds. So, hopefully its clear how multiple builds could pile up if they're all started during the 15m window that the first build is processing its parallel block. If 5 builds were queued up in that time, then as soon as the 5th one's parallel block ends, I get 5 reports instantaneously from all 5 builds 'finishing' at once.

Comment: Yep.  So, unfortunately, what you're describing is the expected behavior, and I caution you about trying to change it.  You may have multiple slaves configured on the same machine.  If your post-run task is truly that fast, then you may want to give it it's own slave on the same machine as master.  Doing this will ensure that you always have an executor available for JUST the post-run.

Comment: If you want to start trying to manipulate your build queue for a node, which again, I advise against, then make sure you understand all the implications and side effects, because you may destabilize the executor queue and create a whole slew of problems for you.  Not to mention the added complexity that it would require.  Keep in mind that complexity is just as much a cost as the time it takes to execute, simplicity goes a long way, especially for programmatically defined build orchestration

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice. Turns out the Lockable Resources Plugin is all I needed to get the effect I want: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin

Comment: Cool plugin!  Good luck, thanks for sharing your find